# How to detect the white gauge board for measuring the level of the water?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I work on a project where I need to measure water level using a white gauge board. Currently my approach is:

1. segmenting the white gauge board.
2. measure the water level against the gauge board.

But I get stuck in segmenting the gauge board. I avoid using color-based segmentation since I need it to be invariant with light changes, so I detect the edges using morphological operations instead. I've got this image:

[image] [image]

The result from morphological operations seems promising. The edges on the white gauge board are sharper than others. But I still don't have any idea to properly segment the board. Can you suggest an algorithm to segment the board? Or please suggest if you have different algorithm for measuring the water level.

Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("image.jpg");
    if (!src.data)
        return -1;

    cv::Mat bw;
    cv::cvtColor(src, bw, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::medianBlur(bw, bw, 3);

    cv::Mat dilated, eroded;
    cv::dilate(bw, dilated, cv::Mat());
    cv::erode(bw, eroded, cv::Mat());
    bw = dilated - eroded;

    cv::imshow("src", src);
    cv::imshow("bw", bw);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using C++, but I'm open to other implementations in Matlab/Mathematica.

Comment: Is your camera in a fixed location? How much do the images of the gauge vary?

Comment: @DCS Yes we can assume that the camera is in a fixed location. Perhaps the color of the image will vary a bit e.g: morning, evening, etc.

Comment: If the camera is in a fixed location, can't you just hard-code the gauge board segmentation?

Comment: @FlorianBrucker: That's why I asked... :)

Comment: Where's the water level on that image?

Comment: You might get more complete answers if you provide a few example pictures to work with (not just one).  Then we can actually test the method instead of just giving suggestions that may or may not work well for your actual images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the camera is indeed stationary, you can use this type of quick and dirty approach:

```
im= rgb2gray(imread('img.jpg'));
imr=imrotate(im,1);
a=imr(100:342,150);
plot(a)
```

[image]

The minima that are shown in the plot are from 10 (left) to 1 (right) in the scale of the indicator. You can use a peak detector to locate their positions and interpolate the water level found between them.
So, there's no real need of fancy image processing...

Comment: What is the `imr` function? Can you point me to the documentation page? I tried to google it but I cannot find it.

Comment: `imr` is the name I gave the output of `imrotate`, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html

Answer (score 0):

Why are you segmenting the gauge board anyway? You just want to find it in the image, that's all. You don't need to find the relative location of segments. 5 is always going to be between 4 and 6.

As you've probably noticed, you can find the rough location of the gauge board by looking for an area with a high contrast level. Using `matchTemplate` you can then find the exact location. (Considering that the camera is fixed, you might be able to skip the first step and call `matchTemplate` directly).